# Setting up FPC and Lazarus for iOS development on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, installation, lazarus, fpc

I have tried to follow an article which is supposed to work to
make an iOS dev enviroment work with FPC and Lazarus,
but like always, nothing works the first time.

The article can be found here: http://blog.naver.com/simonsayz

Everything in that article works fine until I get to the point of installing the Arm iOS crosscompiler which asks for the path of the iPhone SDK.

When I enter the correct path, it stops and asks me to try again and says I must've entered the wrong path.

Is there an article somewhere which WORKS so that I can install FPC, Lazarus and all iOS related stuff including some examples so that I can get started with my iOS app development?

Answer (score 0):

Most knowledge about these issues is on the Mac Pascal maillist and their archives (which iirc are subscribers only):

https://lists.sonic.net/mailman/listinfo/mac-pascal

Maybe SDK versionitis?

Comment: Different versions, e.g. that the example was meant for an older version and something changed.

Comment: oh, I dont know to be honest.